# Is it true that for any set $X,Y \subseteq \Bbb A^n(k)$, $I(X) = I(Y )$ iff $X = Y$ .

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is it true that for any set $X,Y \subseteq \Bbb A^n(k)$, $I(X) = I(Y )$ iff $X = Y$ . Because I know $I(X) = I(Y )$ implies $\overline X=\overline Y$ But I am thinking that this is not true because if I take $Y=\overline X$ then $I(X) = I(\overline X )$ but $X \neq \overline X$ always.

But in this paper http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2010/REUPapers/Bloom.pdf

I am getting one proof The following are the first basic properties of these objects, and these properties
are easy to verify.
(1) If $X ⊂ Y$ , then $I(X) ⊃ I(Y )$, so this correspondence is inclusion-reversing.
Moreover, $I(X) = I(Y ) ⇐⇒ X = Y $.

We give a construction which will be useful later:

**Proposition 1.9. Let $P_1, P_2, . . . , P_n$ be distinct points in $A^
n$. Then, $\exists$
polynomials $F_i ∈ k[X_1, X_2, . . . , X_n]$ such that $F_i(P_j ) = δ_{ij} =0$ if $i \neq j$
and $1$ if $i = j$.**

**Proof.** For each $i$, let $V_i = \{P_1, . . . , P_{i−1}, P_{i+1}, . . . , P_n\}$. Then, from the first
property above, $V_i \subsetneq V_i ∪ \{P_i\}$ implies $I(V_i) \supsetneq I (V_i ∪ \{P_i\})$. Pick $G_i ∈
I (V_i ∪ {P_i}) - I(V_i)$. $G_i$
is zero on $V_i$
, but is non-zero on $P_i$
. Thus, our desired
polynomials are $F_i =\frac 1{G_i(P_i)}Gi$.

So this whole proposition is false right?

Comment: over an algebraically closed field $k$ we have $I(X) = I(Y)$ if and only if $\bar{X} = \bar{Y}$.

Comment: @basket May I ask what exactly $\bar{X}$ means in this context.

Comment: @basket Yes you are true then what about the proposition?

Comment: @user160110 $\overline X$ means the closure of $X$ in the Zarisky topology $\Bbb A^n$

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I(X) is all the polynomials equal to zero in every point of X? Then, in R^n if X is any set with a volume, then I(X)={0}. What do I miss?

Comment: Your definition is correct. But do you mean by volume?

Comment: @user152715 In R^n by volume I mean Jordan measure.

Comment: I don't know about that sorry.. :(

Comment: @user152715 I have reading your paper, and I might return to this later, but I found that if $X$ is finite then $\overline{X}=X$(property (5) page 2). Since $V_i$ is finite, it seems that alot of the problems you were having clear up.

Answer (score 1):

The correspondence you mentioned, $X = Y$ if and only if $I(X) = I(Y)$, is only valid when $X, Y$ are assumed to be **closed** subsets of $\mathbb{A}^n(k)$.  In the proposition you mentioned, all the sets which they were dealing with were closed, so there is no trouble there.

For an example when $I(X) = I(Y)$ holds, but $X \neq Y$, take $n = 1, X = \mathbb{A}^1(k)$, and $Y$ any proper subset of $X$ which has infinitely many elements.  Since $X$ and $Y$ are both infinite, $I(X) = I(Y) = (0)$, because a nonzero polynomial over a field in one variable cannot have infinitely many roots.

Comment: I don't understand. You say X=Y<=>I(X)=I(Y) (sets closed), but in the second paragraph you give a counter-example.

Comment: In my example, $X$ is closed, but $Y$ is not closed.

Comment: Let k be real numbers, X=[1;2], Y=[3;4], both are closed, I(X)=I(Y)={0}. What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you saying $X$ is the closed interval $[1,2]$?  That is not a closed set in the Zariski topology.

Comment: I see, so closed sets on R would be either whole R or finite. Thank you for the clarification.